# toolbar containing multiple layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I am new to Android. Now I am trying to make a new app which contains one toolbar.
It contains two layouts
1) showing title and other information
2) Searching for content

Only one shows at a time, through a button click.

When below recycerview scrolls, toolbar scroll off. But I don't want to happen that for the second layout.

I want the toolbar to pin at the top. How to do that?

recommend any GitHub project which hides one layout at a time in toolbar.

Comment: follow the following links https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: I already read the first link in a couple of days ago. are you sure there is anything for me to make toolbar to pin and scroll of for different layouts

Comment: sorry, I am not well in english